# How to draw a rounded rectangle (rectangle with rounded corners) with OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, rounded-corners, rectangles

How can I draw a rectangle with rounded corners in OpenCV? I know that the functions ellipse() and line() can be simply put together to draw it. I just wonder if someone has done it before and has put it in a proper function so I can use it? Ideally the corner radius is to calibrate  in a parameter.

I searched a lot for that, but it seems no one had that problem before. If no one has such I function I will probably post my own solution here in a few days.

Answer (score 16):

I realized, this is much easier that I thought. Here is my function. I hope it is helpful for someone.

```
/**
 * Draws a rectangle with rounded corners, the parameters are the same as in the OpenCV function @see rectangle();
 * @param cornerRadius A positive int value defining the radius of the round corners.
 * @author K
 */
void rounded_rectangle( Mat& src, Point topLeft, Point bottomRight, const Scalar lineColor, const int thickness, const int lineType , const int cornerRadius)
{
    /* corners:
     * p1 - p2
     * |     |
     * p4 - p3
     */
    Point p1 = topLeft;
    Point p2 = Point (bottomRight.x, topLeft.y);
    Point p3 = bottomRight;
    Point p4 = Point (topLeft.x, bottomRight.y);
    
    // draw straight lines
    line(src, Point (p1.x + cornerRadius, p1.y), Point (p2.x - cornerRadius, p2.y), lineColor, thickness, lineType);
    line(src, Point (p2.x, p2.y + cornerRadius), Point (p3.x, p3.y - cornerRadius), lineColor, thickness, lineType);
    line(src, Point (p4.x + cornerRadius, p4.y), Point (p3.x-cornerRadius, p3.y), lineColor, thickness, lineType);
    line(src, Point (p1.x, p1.y + cornerRadius), Point (p4.x, p4.y - cornerRadius), lineColor, thickness, lineType);
    
    // draw arcs
    ellipse( src, p1 + Point(cornerRadius, cornerRadius), Size( cornerRadius, cornerRadius ), 180.0, 0, 90, lineColor, thickness, lineType );
    ellipse( src, p2 + Point(-cornerRadius, cornerRadius), Size( cornerRadius, cornerRadius ), 270.0, 0, 90, lineColor, thickness, lineType );
    ellipse( src, p3 + Point(-cornerRadius, -cornerRadius), Size( cornerRadius, cornerRadius ), 0.0, 0, 90, lineColor, thickness, lineType );
    ellipse( src, p4 + Point(cornerRadius, -cornerRadius), Size( cornerRadius, cornerRadius ), 90.0, 0, 90, lineColor, thickness, lineType );
}
```

Comment: It will be good that the `cornerRadius` be calculated automatically, because when you draw a small size Rectangle, then it will look like a circle, so the `cornerRadius` can be calculated like this `cornerRadius = (rect.width+rect.height)*0.1`

Answer (score 11):

Here is the python version with filled/not filled feature and corner_radius automatically calculated based on the image's height.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def rounded_rectangle(src, top_left, bottom_right, radius=1, color=255, thickness=1, line_type=cv2.LINE_AA):

    #  corners:
    #  p1 - p2
    #  |     |
    #  p4 - p3

    p1 = top_left
    p2 = (bottom_right[1], top_left[1])
    p3 = (bottom_right[1], bottom_right[0])
    p4 = (top_left[0], bottom_right[0])

    height = abs(bottom_right[0] - top_left[1])

    if radius > 1:
        radius = 1

    corner_radius = int(radius * (height/2))

    if thickness < 0:

        #big rect
        top_left_main_rect = (int(p1[0] + corner_radius), int(p1[1]))
        bottom_right_main_rect = (int(p3[0] - corner_radius), int(p3[1]))

        top_left_rect_left = (p1[0], p1[1] + corner_radius)
        bottom_right_rect_left = (p4[0] + corner_radius, p4[1] - corner_radius)

        top_left_rect_right = (p2[0] - corner_radius, p2[1] + corner_radius)
        bottom_right_rect_right = (p3[0], p3[1] - corner_radius)

        all_rects = [
        [top_left_main_rect, bottom_right_main_rect], 
        [top_left_rect_left, bottom_right_rect_left], 
        [top_left_rect_right, bottom_right_rect_right]]

        [cv2.rectangle(src, rect[0], rect[1], color, thickness) for rect in all_rects]

    # draw straight lines
    cv2.line(src, (p1[0] + corner_radius, p1[1]), (p2[0] - corner_radius, p2[1]), color, abs(thickness), line_type)
    cv2.line(src, (p2[0], p2[1] + corner_radius), (p3[0], p3[1] - corner_radius), color, abs(thickness), line_type)
    cv2.line(src, (p3[0] - corner_radius, p4[1]), (p4[0] + corner_radius, p3[1]), color, abs(thickness), line_type)
    cv2.line(src, (p4[0], p4[1] - corner_radius), (p1[0], p1[1] + corner_radius), color, abs(thickness), line_type)

    # draw arcs
    cv2.ellipse(src, (p1[0] + corner_radius, p1[1] + corner_radius), (corner_radius, corner_radius), 180.0, 0, 90, color ,thickness, line_type)
    cv2.ellipse(src, (p2[0] - corner_radius, p2[1] + corner_radius), (corner_radius, corner_radius), 270.0, 0, 90, color , thickness, line_type)
    cv2.ellipse(src, (p3[0] - corner_radius, p3[1] - corner_radius), (corner_radius, corner_radius), 0.0, 0, 90,   color , thickness, line_type)
    cv2.ellipse(src, (p4[0] + corner_radius, p4[1] - corner_radius), (corner_radius, corner_radius), 90.0, 0, 90,  color , thickness, line_type)

    return src
```

Usage:

```
top_left = (0, 0)
bottom_right = (500, 800)
color = (255, 255, 255)
image_size = (500, 800, 3)
img = np.zeros(image_size)
img = rounded_rectangle(img, top_left, bottom_right, color=color, radius=0.5, thickness=-1)

cv2.imshow('rounded_rect', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Rounded rectangle Filled]

[image: Rounded rectangle Not Filled]

Comment: I wonder how it went unnoticed for over 3 years, but your x/y coordinates are unclear. You need to give this function `top_left=(x1, y1), bottom_right=(y2, x2)`. Since you used `top_left=(0/0)` this went unnoticed! At least in the full rectangle

Answer (score 4):

Here's a Python implementation(in case anyone was looking for one): it draws a rounded corner (of random radius and line thickness --- change that if you want) border around an image:

```
def addRoundedRectangleBorder(img):
    height, width, channels = img.shape

    border_radius = int(width * random.randint(1, 10)/100.0)
    line_thickness = int(max(width, height) * random.randint(1, 3)/100.0)
    edge_shift = int(line_thickness/2.0)

    red = random.randint(230,255)
    green = random.randint(230,255)
    blue = random.randint(230,255)
    color = (blue, green, red)

    #draw lines
    #top
    cv2.line(img, (border_radius, edge_shift), 
    (width - border_radius, edge_shift), (blue, green, red), line_thickness)
    #bottom
    cv2.line(img, (border_radius, height-line_thickness), 
    (width - border_radius, height-line_thickness), (blue, green, red), line_thickness)
    #left
    cv2.line(img, (edge_shift, border_radius), 
    (edge_shift, height  - border_radius), (blue, green, red), line_thickness)
    #right
    cv2.line(img, (width - line_thickness, border_radius), 
    (width - line_thickness, height  - border_radius), (blue, green, red), line_thickness)

    #corners
    cv2.ellipse(img, (border_radius+ edge_shift, border_radius+edge_shift), 
    (border_radius, border_radius), 180, 0, 90, color, line_thickness)
    cv2.ellipse(img, (width-(border_radius+line_thickness), border_radius), 
    (border_radius, border_radius), 270, 0, 90, color, line_thickness)
    cv2.ellipse(img, (width-(border_radius+line_thickness), height-(border_radius + line_thickness)), 
    (border_radius, border_radius), 10, 0, 90, color, line_thickness)
    cv2.ellipse(img, (border_radius+edge_shift, height-(border_radius + line_thickness)), 
    (border_radius, border_radius), 90, 0, 90, color, line_thickness)

    return img
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the code from @author K. make the function have ability to draw filled rounded rectangle if pass -1 as thickness

python version

```
def DrawRoundedRectangle(img, topLeft, bottomRight, radius=1, color=255, thickness=1, line_type=cv.LINE_AA):

min_half = int(min((bottomRight[0] - topLeft[0]), (bottomRight[1] - topLeft[1])) * 0.5)
radius = min(radius, min_half)

# /* corners:
#  * p1 - p2
#  * |     |
#  * p4 - p3
#  */
p1 = topLeft
p2 = (bottomRight[0], topLeft[1])
p3 = bottomRight
p4 = (topLeft[0], bottomRight[1])

if(thickness < 0):
    # // draw rectangle
    cv.rectangle(img, (p1[0] + radius, p1[1]),  (p3[0] - radius, p3[1]), color, thickness, line_type)
    cv.rectangle(img, (p1[0], p1[1] + radius),  (p3[0], p3[1] - radius), color, thickness, line_type)
else:
    # // draw straight lines
    cv.line(img, (p1[0] + radius, p1[1]),  (p2[0] - radius, p2[1]), color, thickness, line_type);
    cv.line(img, (p2[0], p2[1] + radius),  (p3[0], p3[1] - radius), color, thickness, line_type);
    cv.line(img, (p4[0] + radius, p4[1]),  (p3[0]-radius, p3[1]), color, thickness, line_type);
    cv.line(img, (p1[0], p1[1] + radius),  (p4[0], p4[1] - radius), color, thickness, line_type);

# // draw arcs
if(radius > 0):
    cv.ellipse( img, (p1[0] + radius, p1[1] + radius), ( radius, radius ), 180.0, 0, 90, color, thickness, line_type );
    cv.ellipse( img, (p2[0] - radius, p2[1] + radius), ( radius, radius ), 270.0, 0, 90, color, thickness, line_type );
    cv.ellipse( img, (p3[0] - radius, p3[1] - radius), ( radius, radius ), 0.0, 0, 90, color, thickness, line_type );
    cv.ellipse( img, (p4[0] + radius, p4[1] - radius), ( radius, radius ), 90.0, 0, 90, color, thickness, line_type );
```

javascript version

```
function DrawRoundedRectangle(img, topLeft, bottomRight, radius=1, color=255, thickness=1, line_type=cv.LINE_AA){

let min_half = Math.floor(Math.min((bottomRight.x - topLeft.x), (bottomRight.y - topLeft.y)) * 0.5)
radius = Math.min(radius, min_half)

/* corners:
#  * p1 - p2
#  * |     |
#  * p4 - p3
#  */
let p1 = topLeft
let p2 = new cv.Point(bottomRight.x, topLeft.y)
let p3 = bottomRight
let p4 = new cv.Point(topLeft.x, bottomRight.y)

if(thickness < 0){
    // draw rectangle
    cv.rectangle(img, new cv.Point(p1.x + radius, p1.y),  new cv.Point(p3.x - radius, p3.y), color, thickness, line_type)
    cv.rectangle(img, new cv.Point(p1.x, p1.y + radius),  new cv.Point(p3.x, p3.y - radius), color, thickness, line_type)
}
else{
    // draw straight lines
    cv.line(img, new cv.Point(p1.x + radius, p1.y),  new cv.Point(p2.x - radius, p2.y), color, thickness, line_type);
    cv.line(img, new cv.Point(p2.x, p2.y + radius),  new cv.Point(p3.x, p3.y - radius), color, thickness, line_type);
    cv.line(img, new cv.Point(p4.x + radius, p4.y),  new cv.Point(p3.x-radius, p3.y), color, thickness, line_type);
    cv.line(img, new cv.Point(p1.x, p1.y + radius),  new cv.Point(p4.x, p4.y - radius), color, thickness, line_type);
}
// draw arcs
if(radius > 0){
    cv.ellipse( img, new cv.Point(p1.x + radius, p1.y + radius), new cv.Size( radius, radius ), 180.0, 0, 90, color, thickness, line_type );
    cv.ellipse( img, new cv.Point(p2.x - radius, p2.y + radius), new cv.Size( radius, radius ), 270.0, 0, 90, color, thickness, line_type );
    cv.ellipse( img, new cv.Point(p3.x - radius, p3.y - radius), new cv.Size( radius, radius ), 0.0, 0, 90, color, thickness, line_type );
    cv.ellipse( img, new cv.Point(p4.x + radius, p4.y - radius), new cv.Size( radius, radius ), 90.0, 0, 90, color, thickness, line_type );
}
}
```