# Convert image to rounded corners in opencv

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv3.0

I want to convert corners of image to rounded corners. How to do it using opencv? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can draw a mask that contains a rounded rectangle using this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18975399/4253931 and then apply the mask to your image.

Comment: I doubt that it is going to solve my problem

Comment: Could you explain why or edit your question to clarify what exactly you want to achieve?